# Google charts text padding and hide axis lines

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a problem with google charts.

1. How to make padding between horizontal axil line and labels. And align them differently (first to right, last - to left) - so, they will be inside chart area
2. How can i remove vertical axis at the end of the chart and leave only zero axis.

code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawBasic);

function drawBasic () {
  let data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data1.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data1.addColumn('number', 'K/D');

  data1.addRows([
     [new Date(2016, 11, 11), 0], [new Date(2016, 11, 12), 10], [new Date(2016, 11, 13), 43], [new Date(2016, 11, 14), 20], [new Date(2016, 11, 15), 56],]);
  let options1 = {
    height: 125,
    chartArea: {
      left: 30,
      top: 10,
      right: 30,
      bottom: 20
    },
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    colors: ['#3ec8de'],
    tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    hAxis: {
      format: 'dd.M',
      gridlines: {
        color: '#333',
      },
      ticks: [new Date(2016, 11, 11), new Date(2016, 11, 15)]
    },
   vAxis: {
    gridlines: {
      count: 3,
      color: 'transparent',
    }
   },
  crosshair: {trigger: 'both', orientation: 'vertical', color: '#b5b5b5'}
 };

 let chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('overtime-chart1'));

chart1.draw(data1, options1);
}
```

[Here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F13Z5.jpg).

[And this is link to codepen with code](http://codepen.io/makedonec88/pen/bBmxxw)

Comment: did you check https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options

Comment: of course) But it's so much information there. So maybe I missed main part. I've tried 'vAxis.textPosition' but it's only positioned label inside or outside chart. And not align text. And 'Axis.textStyle' where you can specify text style. But not something like line-height, unfortunately :-(